# SAX/StAX parser without web calls

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am using the SAX parser included with java and I noticed something I don't understand/find annoying.

I am using a SAX parser to run though hundreds of XML documents where in only need to actually parse a few of them. If the first element in the document does not have the correct namespace I will simply terminate and continue to the next document.

But a document takes betweem 200-600ms to initiate before it even starts reading. I couldn't figure out why before I accidentally turned off my internet while developing and got loads of this exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: hibernate.sourceforge.net
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1304)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1270)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:264)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1161)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at dk.magenta.alfresco.GenerateJavaMojo$Finder.find(GenerateJavaMojo.java:188)
    at dk.magenta.alfresco.GenerateJavaMojo$Finder.visitFile(GenerateJavaMojo.java:215)
    at dk.magenta.alfresco.GenerateJavaMojo$Finder.visitFile(GenerateJavaMojo.java:160)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at dk.magenta.alfresco.GenerateJavaMojo.execute(GenerateJavaMojo.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

So the question is twofold: Why is the sax parser spending all that time connecting to web URL's, and can i turn it off or is there an implementation where I can turn it off?

Update:
I have tried adding an EntityResolver like this.

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setValidating(false);
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
saxParser.getXMLReader().setEntityResolver(new DummyEntityResolver());

....

public class DummyEntityResolver implements EntityResolver {

        public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicID, String systemID)
                throws SAXException {

            return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
        }
    }
```

It has no effect. The calls are still 400ms on average and is almost instant when the Internet is unavailable.

Comment: Do them XML files have any DTD or XSD or XSL declarations? A sample XML would help.

Comment: Many of them have both. I am basically parsing XML files in a bunch of JAR dependefncies, which includes a LOT of Spring JARs.

Answer (score 1):

The documents probably contain a reference to an external DTD held at that location. If the external DTD contains entities that need to be expanded then it may be impossible to parse without it, but if you know that isn't the case, or if you have a copy of the DTD locally, then you can set an EntityResolver on the XML parser that redirects the references to a local file. If you don't want to write your own EntityResolver you could also use an Oasis Catalog to redirect references to local copies, but unless you're scared of writing any Java that's more complicated to set up.

Comment: And there is no way to just completely disable DTD validation? Actually, if i could just disable DTD validation for the first element and then re-enable it afterwards that would be ideal. Basically I check the first element only to decide if I need to actually parse the file.

Comment: Disabling validation doesn't disable reading the DTD, because the DTD is used for things other than validation: specifically, for entity expansion.

Comment: So if I want to be able to just look at the first tag without web calls I guess you are saying that I will have to do some pre-validation without using an XML parser at all? Am i bound for the unholy realm of parsing the XML file as a String?

Comment: My advice was to set an EntityResolver on your XML parser, you seem to be ignoring that advice.

Comment: No i have an EntitiyResolver setup to no effect. I will update the question.

Comment: You may need to install a network monitoring tool of some kind (e.g Charles) to see what resources are being fetched from the internet, so that you can find out where the calls are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the parser is spending time connecting to the internet to download external DTDs. Since those XMLs are from standard, public libraries which have already been validated, I recommend you to disable validation through:

```
SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory=SAXParserFactory.getInstance();
saxParserFactory.setValidating(false);
SAXParser saxParser=saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
```

Comment: Disabling validation is not usually enough to prevent the DTD being read, because the DTD is also used for entity expansion.

Comment: I can confirm that calling #setValidating(false) is not enough. The same behavior is observed, meaning that the calls still take 400ish ms to complete unless I cut then internet connectivity.